# Toggle and give width to another DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I am not great with JQuery and my advisor is currently sleeping - I need to make disappear -with animation- left DIV and give its original width to the right one, which I want to make wider in the same time (also with animation) - I hope this is clear. Practically, get rid of the left sidebar onclick and this operation will make content on right wider.

Have you seen something for this?

Thanks,

mP

Comment: How about waiting for the advisor?

Comment: Yeah, its almost midnight and I d like to solve this last piece of *** :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.left-sidebar').click(function(e){
    var originalWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).animate({width: '0px'}, 400, linear, function(e){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('.right-sidebar').animate({width: originalWidth}, 400, linear);
});
```

Assumptions:

- Left sidebar has class "left-sidebar", right sidebar has class "right-sidebar".
- The left sidebar needs to be hidden after it is animated.

Explore [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for customization.